# Conjunction "either ": no paraphrase with "any"

Tags: meaning, pronouns, definition

> When **either** is used as a conjunction, no paraphrase with **any** is
> available, and so *either* is unexceptionable even when it applies to
> more than two clauses:
>
> ***Either** the union will make a counter-offer **or**
> the original bid will be refused by the board **or** the deal will go
> ahead as scheduled.*

What does it refer to by ["no paraphrase with **any**"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=either)?

Comment: You should provide an example to make the question clear.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary you link to is pointing out different ways 'either' is used.

A) as a pronoun referring to **two** things, or

B) as a conjunction, where it can be used to link **two or more** things.

When used as a pronoun, you **cannot** use 'either' to refer to more than two items. Instead you can use 'any'. But you cannot use 'any' as a conjunction, therefore 'no paraphrase with any is available'. To put this in simpler terms: you cannot use 'any' to replace 'either' when it is used as a conjunction.

For instance:

**Pronouns**

> Q: Which of these two apples do you want? A: Either!

> Q: Which of these four apples do you want? A: Any!

**Conjunctions**

> Either I want the red apple or the green one.

> Either I want the red apple, or the green one, or an orange, or a banana.